# Kotlin string concatenation - preserving indents with multiline strings

Tags: kotlin, string-concatenation

Kotlin's multiline string handling is wonderful in so many ways, and it's ability to `.trimIndent()` allows you to keep a string literal indented with the rest of the code like so:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myString = """
    hello
    world
""".trimIndent()

println(myString)
```

Will print out:

```
hello
world
```

without the literal indents present in the code.  But this breaks down when using Kotlin's powerful string templating system if the value being inserted is multiline:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myString = """
    hello
    world
""".trimIndent()
    
    println("""
        teststring2
        $myString
    """.trimIndent())
}
```

will print out

```
            teststring2
            hello
world
```

This appears to happen because the `world` is on a new line and doesn't receive the indentation that `hello` gets.  Is there an **elegant** way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the first string literal.  (To avoid confusion, I'll use underscores to represent spaces.)

```
____hello
____world
```

Its `trimIndent()` call will remove the spaces, leaving it with no indentation, like this:

```
hello
world
```

The second string looks like this:

```
________teststring2
________$myString
```

Then the `$myString` will be substituted precisely with the contents of the first:

```
________teststring2
________hello
world
```

Note that the indentation that was before `$myString` remains, giving the spaces you see before the "hello"; but there's no indentation within `myString`, so you don't see any before "world".

Now, [`trimIndent()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim-indent.html) removes “a common minimal indent of all the input lines”.  But there's no common indent here, because of the last line.  So the second `trimIndent()` call does nothing.

As to what to do, there are probably several options.  If you don't want any indents, then the most obvious would be to remove *all* indents, not just common ones.  (I don't think there's a dedicated function in the standard library, but it should be easy enough to write one.  For example, you could do a regular expression replace of `"^  *"` with `""`.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in practice, not [trimIndent()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim-indent.html#trimindent)'s problem. @gidds has explained it very clearly. If you want to achieve what you want, you can use [trimMargin()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim-indent.html#trimindent).

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myString = """
    hello
    world
""".trimIndent()
    
    println("""
        |teststring2
        |$myString
    """.trimMargin())
}
```

Output:

```
teststring2
hello
world
```